# Setting getColumnClass in a JTable with a ResultSet TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem.
I create a  DefaultTableModel like this -->

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(1,1);
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {   
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>(10,2);

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

The ResulSet is filled with some Data of a MySQL Database.
After that I create a JTable with the DataModel and override set the tableproperties:

```
this.table = new JTable(buildTableModel(this.rs)){
        // Make Cells uneditable
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {  
                if(table.getColumnName(column).contains("key")) return false;
                if(table.getColumnName(column).contains("datum")) return false;
                if(table.getColumnName(column).contains("user")) return false;
                return true;               
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                Class<?> classType;
                if(columnIndex == 1)
                    classType = Boolean.class;
                else
                    classType = String.class;
                return classType;
            }
        };
```

If I don't use the second part (@Override getColumClass), it works fine, but if I add the getColumnClass part, I get this errormessage:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

The field contains "true" / "false".
I'm doing something pretty wrong, but I have really no idea what exactly ;-(
Can someone help me out with that?

Thanks a lot

Edit:
I changed the buildTableModel to this:

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();


    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>(1,1);
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>(10,2);

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {

            if(rs.getObject(columnIndex).toString().equals("true"))
                vector.add(Boolean.TRUE);
            else        
            if(rs.getObject(columnIndex).toString().equals("false"))
                vector.add(Boolean.FALSE);
            else
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }

        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

and now it works ;-)

Comment: Post the stack trace. We don't even know what line is causing the exception.

Comment: It's this line: 
classType = Boolean.class;
How do I get the stack trace?

Comment: No, that line can't possibly cause an exception. Use try / catch and then in the catch(Exception ex) block , add ex.printStackTrace(). The stack trace should appear in  the console.

Comment: BTW, your code suggests that only the first column is a Boolean and the rest are all strings so make sure that the data you retrieve match those types.

Comment: Hey, I used this: 
 try
  {  
  UpdateGrid grid = new UpdateGrid("test");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
  } 
over the class initialization, but no matter what, it won't change the exception output:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean ....
I'm sorry, I'm not that good in programming yet, so I'm really helpless ;-(
Btw. it's not the line --> classType = Boolean.class; that triggers the exception,but it's because of it. If I return String.class,no error occurs

Comment: I can't be sure (and we still dont have the stack trace) but I think that you're trying to assign a String value to a Boolean column (in your Swing table), which causes a ClassCast exception. Show us your DB table as well as the code retrieving the data.

Comment: Hey, yes, I just figured out, that if I use this DataModel:

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Hey, your tip with the match of the retrieved data helped me a lot. 
I fixed the problem with this --> if(rs.getObject(columnIndex).toString().equals("true"))
           vector.add(Boolean.TRUE);
          else     
          if(rs.getObject(columnIndex).toString().equals("false"))
           vector.add(Boolean.FALSE);
          else
           vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
[ in the buildTableModel function]
Can I somehow accept your comment as answer, because it helped me to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a String value to a Boolean column (in your Swing table). Just make sure that the types of the data (the data model) retrieved match those of the table data model.

Answer (score 2):

[metaData.getColumnType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int)) can returns (note very simple matrix and hardcoded with minimum effort)

```
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        int type;
        try {
            type = metaData.getColumnType(column + 1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return super.getColumnClass(column);
        }
        switch (type) {
            case Types.CHAR:
            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                return String.class;
            case Types.BIT:
                return Boolean.class;
            case Types.TINYINT:
            case Types.SMALLINT:
            case Types.INTEGER:
                return Integer.class;
            case Types.BIGINT:
                return Long.class;
            case Types.FLOAT:
            case Types.DOUBLE:
                return Double.class;
            case Types.DATE:
                return java.sql.Date.class;
            default:
                return Object.class;
        }
    }
```